# An official sheet or ...?

Tags: word-usage

**1-** I would appreciate it if someone could tell me that what the natives call the official sheet of a company, with the name and address of this company printed at the top?
Please consider the following image:
[image]

Meanwhile I would be thankful if you could let me whether the following terms are idiomatic in English or you use some other equivalents for them:

**-2-** Company statute

**-3-** Gazette (an official newspaper which contains the latest changes of the company's officials and responsible)

Comment: I think "official letterhead" is the usual term.

Comment: 1 - Letterhead [UK English]

2 - don't know

3 - Gazette, newsletter, press release. Depends on the form it takes & who it will be distributed to.

Comment: @Tetsujin regarding #2, what do you think of 'articles of associations'. Do you have such a term in your legal encyclopedia and statute?

Comment: I really don't know, sorry. I'm a retired musician - we're not really known for our business acumen ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin you are very welcome. :-) 
Just one more question about #3. Regarding this specific one (the qiestion #3), I am going to send a company's resume and background legal documents to someone else; but I really do not know what can I call such a document from among the list you provided above. According to the Longman dictionary, (---Press release = an official statement giving information to the newspapers, radio, or television. ---) >>> (--- Newsletter = a short written report of news about a club, organization etc that is sent regularly to people who are interested. ---)

Comment: And finally, >>> (Gazette = an official newspaper, especially one from the government giving important lists of people who have been employed by them etc.) ===> Consequently, I think the only correct choice would be "newsletter". Do you conform it?

Comment: If the person you are sending it to is then going to redistribute the information, then press release. If he's going to read it for himself, newsletter. Gazette would work, but sounds slightly more officious.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks a million. It was really helpful for me. :-)

Comment: Gazette is not standardized AmE usage here.

Answer (score 1):

> I would appreciate it if someone could tell me that what the natives call the official sheet of a company, with the name and address of this company printed at the top?

It's called *letterhead*.

> Company statute

In a company's charter, the rules outlined there are called *bylaws*.

However, insofar as rules created by your boss and others in authority above you - which may or may not be written down - popular ones for that include *policies* and *guidelines*.

> Gazette (an official newspaper which contains the latest changes of the company's officials and responsible)

*Newsletter* is the traditional term here and probably the most appropriate.

These days this may be done via email, if internal to the company only, and the term I've heard used is *communique* - though that's a generic term for any company-wide email in a pretty format.